# Which folder is served first? assets, lib or vendors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that all of these will be compiled together into one file but the order of this is *very* important for me when compiling the stylesheet as it determines whether the layout is completely messed up or not.

Also, how do I change the order for this?

**assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*  
  *= require jquery-ui
  *= require css-sprites
  *= require formtastic
  *= require style
*/
```

**lib/stylesheets/lib.css**

```
/*  
  *= require reset
*/
```

Is there a way I can load specifically the reset.css I have in my **lib/assets/stylesheets** folder *before* my application.css? or perhaps I could call it from within the file itself somehow? I've tried but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have an `application` folder in every of these 3 folders where I put all the files I want included in every pages.

Then I have an `application_vendor.css` in vendor where I do `require_tree ./application`.
Same for lib, `application_libs` -> `require_tree ./application`

And then in your `application.css` that you include in the layout, you can do:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require application_libs
 *= require application_vendor
 *= require_tree ./application
 *= require other_stuff
*/
```

That way you can choose the order.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you have an application folder in each of the 3 folders? Do you mean like `assets/stylesheets/application_vendor` or do you mean `vendor/assets/stylesheets/applications` ? Doesn't the former kind of defeat the purpose of having the vendor and lib folders?

Comment: I meant `vendor/assets/stylesheets/application`, `lib/assets/stylesheets/application` ;)

Comment: I have tried including css files from the `vendor` and `lib` folder but i get an error telling me that the app can't find the files. I've done it exaclty like you did. What does require_self do btw?

Comment: You have your `vendor/assets/stylesheets/application_vendor.css` where you `/*= require_tree ./application */`, and your `lib/assets/stylesheets/application_lib.css` where you `/*= require_tree */`?

Comment: My `vendor/assets/stylesheets/vendor.css` where I have `/*= require_tree .` I would like to include this in my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` by doing `/*= require lib`. Any idea how I could achieve this? Because creating an application folder in the vendor and lib folders isn't making much sense to me :s

Comment: This should work! (except that you wrote lib instead of vendor in your comment). The only reason I have an application folder is that I don't want to include ALL the libs and ALL the files I might have in my vendor directory on every pages.

Comment: I fixed it. I needed to restart my production server in order for it to work. Thanks for your help though!